# CMake and configure_file: what if I need $ONLY instead of @ONLY?

Tags: cmake

As from the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) of `configure_file`, it has an useful `@ONLY` parameter used to:

> Restrict variable replacement to references of the form `@VAR@`. This is useful for configuring scripts that use `${VAR}` syntax.

So far so good.

Now I'm in the case where I've a file that contains both `@FOO@` and `${BAR}` and I want to replace `S{BAR}` with a variable that comes from my `CMakeLists.tx`. On the other side I don't want that `configure_file` tries to replace `@FOO@`.
In other terms, I need something like a `$ONLY` parameter that works as `@ONLY` but for the opposite case.

Is there any chance I can do that with what I have right now?
I tried putting backslashes in front of my `@`, but this way I obtain a file that contains a couple of `\@` and this is not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least I found a solution that works, even if I'm not sure that's the best approach ever.
I leave it as an answer for future readers in case no solutions come up.

Suppose the line to be elaborated looks like this:

```
@DontTouchMe@/${PROJECT_NAME}
```

To be able to skip the `@DontTouchMe@` part when you pass the file to `configure_file`, you can change the line as it follows:

```
@@Workaround@DontTouchMe@Workaround@@/${PROJECT_NAME}
```

`configure_file` will match and replace `@Workaround@` parts with an empty string and forget about the other `@` around, so that you obtain the following line after the substitution:

```
@DontTouchMe@/TheNameOfTheProject
```

Quite dirty and it could break out with future releases of `cmake` for it actually exploits a *bug* (uhm, I'm not sure I can call it this way actually) of the tool.
Anyway, it works and can be a viable approach for those out there that are still looking for a possible solution.

Comment: Anyone who have found a good way to deal with this yet? I have some perl scripts where I want to users to be able to replace the shebang with the path to their perl binary. Unfortunately the @ is used to define an array. This workaround would be quite messy there.